# connect android to openLDAP server

Tags: java, android, httpclient, openldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I have been assigned a task to, connect to a LDAP server from android.Perform the authetication process from android.I am using openLDAP. I am completely new to this.Can anyone help me out with some piece of code or demo code showing android connecting with LDAP server and authenticating.
The

```
  Port no-389
  SSL Port-636
  IP Address-LGSPC3
  username-->cn=name,cn=users,dc=mydeomain,dc=com

  serverlist-ldap://server1
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

The code I used to connect to LDAP server successfully is as follow:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.AddRequest;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

//String address="ldap://server1.mydomain.com" ;
String address="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
int port=389;
//String bindDN="CN=name,CN=users,DC=mydomain,DC=com";
String bindDN="cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com";
String password="secret";
boolean login_flag=true;

LDAPConnection c ;
AddRequest addRequest;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bt_login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_login);
    bt_login.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") @Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

       try {
           c= new LDAPConnection(address,port,bindDN,password);
           c.setConnectionName("Demo Connection");
           String con_name=c.getConnectionName();
           long time=c.getConnectTime();
           SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
           String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(time));
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Connected to LDAP server....connection_name="+con_name+" at time"+dateString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      } catch (LDAPException e) {
          login_flag=false;
          e.printStackTrace();
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No connection was established" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
           if(login_flag){
                 c.close();
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Closed successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
   }


}

}
```

**Hope it helps you.**